# How to access Data in Json Int, Double, String in Swift?

Tags: ios, json, swift, parameters

I have following Parameters in my json Data.

```
date = "2018-02-12";
"grand_total" = "82.88";
message = "Order Details Details";
status = "order_details";
"sub_total" = 74;
"tax_total" = "8.880000000000001";
time = "06:53:46";
```

How can I set grand total and subtotal to label. In objective c we can directly access any value to string with nsstring string with format but in swift there is no any option like this.

Comment: What you have tried yet. Swift is also developed by apple, so there is not new magic in it.

Comment: Tell me first which format it is  Array or Dictionary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Swift 3**

use  `if let` would be the safest way.

```
if let gTotal = dict["grand_total"] as? Double {
     // gTotal had the double value
}
else if let gTotal = dict["grand_total"] as? Int {
     // gTotal had the int value
}
else {
     // not double nor int value.
}

if let subTotal = dict["sub_total"] as? Double {
    // subTotal had the double value
}
else if let subTotal = dict["sub_total"] as? Int {
    // subTotal had the int value
}
else {
     // not double nor int value.
}

if let message  = dict["message"] as? String {
    // message had the string value
}
else {
    // not string value
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You need to start by parsing the json into an object and then access the data you want to use:

```
if let object = json as? [String:Any] {
    if let total = object["grand_total"] as? Double, let subTotal = object["sub_total"] as? Double {
        // You can now use total and subTotal in here now to set to your labels
        totalLabel.text = "\(total)"
        subTotalLabel.text = "\(subTotal)"
    }
}
```